# Fetching all user created playlists in device

Tags: android, mp3, playlist

I am trying to fetch all the user defined playlists in the device. But I am getting only the default playlists. I tried creating 2 playlists but still I don't get any of my created playlists retrieved. Please help. I am pasting code to create playlist as well as retrieving. 
**EDIT:** Something wrong with creating playlist only. I am able to retrieve playlists created in other music app.

```
public void addToPlaylist(long playlistId, Context context,
        List<Song> playlistTracks, String playlistName) {
    int count = getPlaylistSize(playlistId, context);
    Log.d("playlist size=", "" + count);

    ContentValues[] values = new ContentValues[playlistTracks.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < playlistTracks.size(); i++) {
        values[i] = new ContentValues();
        values[i].put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.PLAY_ORDER, i
                + count + 1);
        values[i].put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID,
                playlistTracks.get(i).getAudioId());
        values[i].put(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME, playlistName);
    }
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external",
            playlistId);
    int num = resolver.bulkInsert(uri, values); 
    Log.d("songs added=", "" + num); // added
    resolver.notifyChange(Uri.parse("content://media"), null);

}
 public void retrieveAllPlaylists(Context context) {

    Uri tempPlaylistURI = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    final String idKey = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID;
    final String nameKey = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME;

    final String[] columns = { idKey, nameKey };

    Cursor playListCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            tempPlaylistURI, columns, null, null, null);

    if (playListCursor != null) {
        Log.d("playlist cursor count=", "" + playListCursor.getCount());

        for (boolean hasItem = playListCursor.moveToFirst(); hasItem; hasItem = playListCursor
                .moveToNext()) {
            playlistName = playListCursor.getString(playListCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(nameKey));
            // noOfTracks = playListCursor.getInt(playListCursor
            // .getColumnIndex(tracksCountKey));
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "playlistname=" + playlistName // returns only default playliststhe
                    + "tracks=" + noOfTracks);
            playlistModel.add(new PlaylistModel(playlistName, noOfTracks));
        }


    }

}
```